# iOS 9 | Contacts framework

Tags: ios, ios9, contacts, abaddressbook

I have app designed for the iOS 8 using the `ABAddressBook framework` for the contact. In iOS 9 the `Contacts framework` is introduced in place of `ABAddressBook`.

To check the effect of this change I checked in the iOS 9 device and everything is working fine.

Is my understanding correct here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever an API/Framework is mentioned as Deprecated it indicates that sometime in future Apple will completely stop supporting the API's. This indicates the developers should move to the new API's soon.

In your case AddressBook Framework is considered as deprecated from iOS9 so Apple will allow these frameworks as of now(may be till iOS10) but that depends on Apple when to stop it completely.

Usually Apple stop supporting the deprecated API after a major release but there are also cases where the deprecated API's survived many major releases.

My suggestion would be move to the Contacts Framework soon.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @iPrabu I have a issue regarding iOS 9 and contact permissions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33065122/contact-permission-again-asked-by-app-on-next-day-app-launch-iphone-ios-9. Can you give some suggestions on it.