# iOS 9 - how to fetch contacts by modification date?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, contacts, abaddressbook

We are developing an iOS 9 app leveraging the new `Contacts Framework`. This app sends to our back-end the contacts of the user (after approval).
We deal with huge contact lists (> 3000) and we would like to only send the updated contacts.

In the old API (ABPerson & co), there was this property: `kABPersonModificationDateProperty.`

But I can't find any equivalent in the new `Contacts Framework` in iOS 9.
I have had a look at `CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification` but we want to capture the changes that occurred even when our app is closed.

Does anyone know how to filter the contact list by modification date or any suitable solution?

Thanks a lot!

**Edit**: I've tried using `ABAddressBook`,`ABPerson` and `kABPersonModificationDateProperty` and I get the modification dates of the contacts with warning for using deprecated code. So that's still an option

Comment: @sujania: thanks for improving my question!

Comment: One way is to continue to use ABAddressbook if no better alternative. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32865313/ios-9-contacts-framework

Comment: I've opened a Radar for this: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5915838058070016

Comment: @Laurent , Found any solution for this?

Comment: @ZaidPathan - unfortunately, not yet :-(
I used the old API ABPerson for awhile but as it's deprecated, it's not sustainable

Comment: @Laurent, Ok bro, I appreciate your response.
Thank you.

Comment: Hey Guys did u found any solution yet..?